# What is the solution of $a^b=a+b$ in terms of $a$?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

> Let $a, b$ be real numbers. Solve
>   $$a^b=a+b$$
>   for $a$.

If there isn't a solution with $a, b$ real, maybe $a, b$ should be complex.

But no matter how hard I try, this is proving to be very difficult to
do. Would anyway be kind enough to show me the solution to this? Thank
you!

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?  Integers, rationals, real ?.  We can help if you specify the complete question and what you have tried. Just by inspection,  $a = -1$, $b = 2$ is a solution.

Comment: @Shialesh I'm not expecting a set of numbers as a solution. I'm expecting one side of the equation to be $a$ and the other side to be something else with $b$.

Comment: With the newly edited question, I'm not sure if we can obtain a closed form. Even with $b$ as natural more than 4, there is no closed form. As for reals, will have to show that the solution given above is the only one.

Comment: @Shialesh Are you sure it's not possible to get a closed form? I think there is, and I think it imvolves the **Lambert W Function**. Unfortunately, I don't know the properties of the Lambert W Function that I could use to solve this equation.

Comment: Have you looked through the examples on wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications

Comment: @AlexZorn Yes, but there are many properties and it admittedly confuses me a lot and would take me a while to learn, so I'd rather ask others who are more experienced than me.

Comment: @6005 I don't understand what you mean, but if it's THAT important, then whatever, add it in.

Comment: @Sam If I say "solve $x^2 = -1$, you might say there are no solutions, but there is a solution if it is over real numbers. Or the solution could be $x = 3$, if you are in $\mathbb{Z} / 10 \mathbb{Z}$. It doesn't make any sense to "solve" an equation if you don't know what set the numbers are coming from.

Comment: @6005 That is not the same as this. In that, you can solve for x being a specific value ($i$). You didn't say that the solution **isn't** complex, or that the solution is strictly real, but it's implied that the solution is complex. I just want to isolate $a$ on one side of the equation, regardless of what kind of number $a$ and $b$ are.

Comment: Am I the only one who cannot see where should be used the Lambert W ? I mean if the problem is to solve the equations for $a$ isn't this a polynomial ?

Comment: @RenatoFaraone read the Second answer.

Comment: Yes in fact it is solved for $b$ and not for $a$ @Sam

Comment: @RenatoFaraone It would be very difficult, if not impossible, to solve for $a$.

Comment: @Sam but you said "Solve *eq.* for $a$" pls edit you question...

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Yes I did say solve for $a$, but if you look at when it's solved for b, a is contained in a jumbled mess that makes it hard to isolate $a$, especially since it's inside the **Lambert W function**. It's not what I wanted, but what want I could be impossible to do.

Answer (score 3):

I will use Lambert-W function defined as the following:

$$W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$$

Your equation:
$$a^b=a+b$$

Multiply it by $a^a$ to make the exponent more "friendly" and use some tricks

$$a^{a+b}=(a+b)a^a$$
$$\frac{1}{a+b}a^{a+b}=a^a$$
$$(a+b)a^{-(a+b)}=a^{-a}$$
$$-(a+b)a^{-(a+b)}=-a^{-a}$$
$$-\ln(a)(a+b)e^{-\ln(a)(a+b)}=-\ln(a)a^{-a}$$
$$-\ln(a)(a+b)= W(-\ln(a)a^{-a})$$
$$a+b= -\frac{W(-\ln(a)a^{-a})}{\ln(a)}$$
$$b= -\frac{W(-\ln(a)a^{-a})}{\ln(a)}-a$$

When solving for $b$ is easy, solving for $a$ is not and I'm not sure if even possible using known functions.

**EDIT:** Here is the [plot of $a(b)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/06v04bns8b).

Comment: Ah, I see. So that's the solution for $b$. I can see why it's hard to solve for $a$, since $a$ is contained in that jumbled mess. Even though you didn't solve for $a$, you did show me why it would be hard to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, if $b=f(a)$, then $a=f(b)$, quite easy to solve for?

Comment: @SimpleArt this is not as easy as you think. If $b=f(a)$ then $a=f^{-1}(b)$ where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of the function, which in this case is very hard as we have pseudo-polynomial with an arbitrary power.

Comment: My mistake.  Its still quite easy to solve though?  Takes the same amount of work you put into your problem in my opinion.

Comment: @SimpleArt try then to solve $a^{\pi}=a+\pi$, as you see in this specific case it's pretty impossible to find the inverse function

Comment: @kamil09875 Use the substitution $a=b-\pi$ to get $b=(b-\pi)^{\pi}$.  Use binomial expansion theorem and solve.  That there, is indeed, beyond my skill to solve, but it is still solvable.

Comment: @SimpleArt do you think this form is easier to solve for $b$? $$b=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\pi\choose n} b^{\pi-n}\pi^n$$ Everything's solvable but often not in the form we need.

Comment: Course not.  I give in to you.  But it is still solvable.  ;D  And I don't like you saying "everything's solvable".  Makes my life feel like a horrible failure...

Comment: @SimpleArt It all boils down what you mean by "solvable". If you want to find a solution using only elementary functions (like exp, log, trigonometric ones etc. but not things like Lambert W) then I seriously doubt this is solvable.

Comment: @Wojowu well... see, I want to solve $xe^{e^x}=e$, but I can't.  With all my Lambert W skills, I can't get into a sort of "closed form" using the lambert W function if necessary.  I can solve $e^{e^x}=x$ using my iterated functions $=x$ method, but I can't do the same for the other, no matter how similar they are.  Any suggestions would be nice.